# Split comma separated items into list in scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

## Issue

I want to extract the keywords from following code and store them as separated list items in json.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
```

So far, I was using the following code:

```
'keywords': [i.split(', ') for i in response.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').extract()]
```

## Result now

This will result in a json-file looking like this:

```
keywords:
     0:
        0: keyword1
        1: keyword2
        2: keyword3
```

Or in raw data like this:

```
{"keywords": [["keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3"]]}
```

## Expected Result

But I need them separated as follows:

```
keywords:
     0:
        0: keyword1
     1:
        0: keyword2
     2:
        0: keyword3
```

Or put in raw data:

```
{"keywords": [["keyword1"], ["keyword2"], ["keyword3"]]}
```

**Any ideas how to solve this?***

Comment: `'keywords': [[[j] for j in i.split(', ')] for i in response.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').extract()]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> sel = Selector(text="""<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">""")
>>> keywords = sel.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').get()
>>> [[i] for i in keywords.split(', ')]
[[u'keyword1'], [u'keyword2'], [u'keyword3']]
```

Or:

```
>>> [[[k] for k in i.split(', ')] for i in sel.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').extract()]
[[[u'keyword1'], [u'keyword2'], [u'keyword3']]]
```

UPD:

Maybe in better to split logics on two cases, like here:

```
>>> keywords = []
>>> for i in sel.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').extract():
...     if ',' in i:
...         for k in i.split(','):
...             keywords.append([k.strip()])
...     else:
...         keywords.append([i.strip()])
... 
>>> keywords
[[u'keyword1'], [u'keyword2'], [u'keyword3']]
```

Comment: Like the answer by Rakesh, works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I have a follow up question on your first approach, since the second one actually results in an unexpected behaviour after all (which you actually noted --> one more square bracket than needed). Well, some keywords are stored all together in one meta-tag while others are stored separately. If they are stored separately, I only have to use `response.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').extract()`. If not, I need your first approach which works as expected. But how to implement this in the code? Like "if there is one meta -tag with many keywords use method one, else use method two".

Comment: I've updated code with separated logics, this should work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing code to,

```
'keywords': [[x] for x in [i.split(', ') for i in response.xpath('//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').extract()]]
```

adding `i.split(', ')` within `[]` will generate individual arrays.

Comment: I am afraid, that it will give `[[[u'keyword1', u'keyword2', u'keyword3']]]`. They will be outside, not inside.

Comment: It will actually result in what I had before. But I appreciate your time, thanks. Rakesh and Vezunchik got it right though.